# How to create NSCollectionView programmatically from scratch?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nscollectionview

`NSCollectionView` remains one of the most mysterious parts of the Cocoa API that I've ever seen.  Documentation is poor and there are many moving parts, many of which are often implemented in Interface Builder, making documentation challenging.

Please provide sample code to create the simplest case of `NSCollectionView` which displays either Text Fields or Buttons without using Xcode where each Text Field or Button has a different Title.  Assume a new Xcode project with the default `window` IBOutlet.

For this example, no binding is required to update the NSCollectionView as the data source changes.  Simply display a grid of prototype objects and set each object's Title to some value.

If we can get a good example of how to do this available to many people, I think it will help everyone who works with `NSCollectionViews` and is as baffled as I am.

**Summary of request**

- Provide sample code to render an NSCollectionView in a new Xcode project
- Do not use Interface Builder, do use the default window IBOutlet provided
- NSCollectionView should contain Text Fields or Buttons, your choice
- Each item in the view should have a different Title
- No binding is required

If there's sample code out there that meets these requirements, please provide a link, that'd be great!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I’m not sure there’s much insight in creating a collection view programmatically and without bindings, but here it goes.

## Introduction

There are essentially four components when using a collection view:

- View: a subclass of `NSView`, responsible for displaying information;
- The collection view itself;
- View controller: a subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` that serves as the collection view item prototype;
- Model: an array of objects.

Usually a view is designed in Interface Builder, and a model is mediated by Cocoa bindings.

Doing it programmatically:

## Constants

```
static const NSSize buttonSize = {80, 20};
static const NSSize itemSize = {100, 40};
static const NSPoint buttonOrigin = {10, 10};
```

## View

This is a standard view (a custom view in Interface Builder parlance) containing a button. Note that the view has fixed size.

```
@interface BVView : NSView
@property (weak) NSButton *button;
@end

@implementation BVView
@synthesize button;
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:(NSRect){frameRect.origin, itemSize}];
    if (self) {
        NSButton *newButton = [[NSButton alloc] 
            initWithFrame:(NSRect){buttonOrigin, buttonSize}];
        [self addSubview:newButton];
        self.button = newButton;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

## View Controller (Prototype)

Normally a view controller loads its view from a nib file. In the rare cases where the view controller doesn’t obtain its view from a nib file, the developer must either send it `-setView:` before `-view` is received by the view controller, or override `-loadView`. The following code does the latter.

View controllers receive the corresponding model object via `-setRepresentedObject:`. I’ve overridden it so as to update the button title whenever the model object changes. Note that this can be accomplished by using Cocoa bindings without any code at all.

Note that none of this code is specific to collection views — it’s general view controller behaviour.

```
@interface BVPrototype : NSCollectionViewItem
@end

@implementation BVPrototype
- (void)loadView {
    [self setView:[[BVView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect]];
}
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
    [[(BVView *)[self view] button] setTitle:representedObject];
}
@end
```

## Model

A simple array of strings representing button titles:

```
@property (strong) NSArray *titles;
self.titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Case", @"Molly", @"Armitage",
    @"Hideo", @"The Finn", @"Maelcum", @"Wintermute", @"Neuromancer", nil];
```

## Collection View

So far, the only relation that’s been established is the view (`BVView`) used by the item prototype (`BVPrototype`). The collection view must be informed of the prototype it should be using as well as the model from which to obtain data.

```
NSCollectionView *cv = [[NSCollectionView alloc]
    initWithFrame:[[[self window] contentView] frame]]; 
[cv setItemPrototype:[BVPrototype new]];
[cv setContent:[self titles]];
```

## Full Source Code for the Application Delegate

```
#import "BVAppDelegate.h"


static const NSSize buttonSize = { 80, 20 };
static const NSSize itemSize = { 100, 40 };
static const NSPoint buttonOrigin = { 10, 10 };


@interface BVView : NSView
@property (weak) NSButton *button;
@end

@implementation BVView
@synthesize button;
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:(NSRect){frameRect.origin, itemSize}];
    if (self) {
        NSButton *newButton = [[NSButton alloc]
            initWithFrame:(NSRect){buttonOrigin, buttonSize}];
        [self addSubview:newButton];
        self.button = newButton;
    }
    return self;
}
@end


@interface BVPrototype : NSCollectionViewItem
@end

@implementation BVPrototype
- (void)loadView {
    [self setView:[[BVView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect]];
}
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
    [[(BVView *)[self view] button] setTitle:representedObject];
}
@end


@interface BVAppDelegate ()
@property (strong) NSArray *titles;
@end

@implementation BVAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize titles;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Case", @"Molly", @"Armitage",
        @"Hideo", @"The Finn", @"Maelcum", @"Wintermute", @"Neuromancer", nil];

    NSCollectionView *cv = [[NSCollectionView alloc]
        initWithFrame:[[[self window] contentView] frame]]; 
    [cv setItemPrototype:[BVPrototype new]];
    [cv setContent:[self titles]];

    [cv setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewMinXMargin
                             | NSViewWidthSizable
                             | NSViewMaxXMargin
                             | NSViewMinYMargin
                             | NSViewHeightSizable
                             | NSViewMaxYMargin)];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:cv];
}

@end
```

Comment: Documentation on NSCollectionView is surprisingly poor.  Anyone who understands how this mythical beast works, and can share their knowledge, is helping out Objective-C developers everywhere. Thanks much.

Comment: Bavarious, may I ask you to show how to sync collection view with mutable array of items?

Comment: @brigadir You need to use bindings.

Comment: So where does the NSCollectionView instance appear? I tried dragging one in IB but I only get a nest of scroll view, clip view etc. No object has  class of "NSCollectionView" to add as outlet to my controller.

Comment: It's inside the Clip view of the NSScrollView (like table, outline and text views)

Comment: I'm passing a non-empty array to `collectionView.content`. However, `-setRepresentedObject:` gets called with an argument of `nil`. What can be happening?

Comment: Can we add NSCollectionView as a subview to NSViewController view? I tried, but `itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath` was not invoked

Answer (score 7):

@Bavarious
You did an excellent job there. This was just an amazing tutorial which I sometimes miss at the Apple Docs.

I rewrote Bavarious' code in Swift (v2) for anyone who's interested:

**//  AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import Cocoa

let buttonSize:NSSize = NSSize(width: 80, height: 20)
let itemSize:NSSize = NSSize(width: 100, height: 40)
let buttonOrigin:NSPoint = NSPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

let titles:[String] = ["Case", "Molly", "Armitage", "Hideo", "The Finn", "Maelcum", "Wintermute", "Neuromancer"]

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let cv = NSCollectionView(frame: self.window.contentView!.frame)
        cv.itemPrototype = BVTemplate()
        cv.content = titles

        cv.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMinXMargin
            .union(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable)
            .union(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxXMargin)
            .union(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMinYMargin)
            .union(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxYMargin)
            .union(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable)

        window.contentView!.addSubview(cv)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

**//  BVTemplate.swift:**

```
import Cocoa

class BVTemplate: NSCollectionViewItem {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func loadView() {
        print("loadingView")
        self.view = BVView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    }

    override var representedObject:AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            if let representedString = representedObject as? String {
                (self.view as! BVView).button?.title = representedString
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**//  BVView.swift:**

```
import Cocoa

class BVView: NSView {

    var button:NSButton?

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: NSRect(origin: frameRect.origin, size: itemSize))
        let newButton:NSButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(origin: buttonOrigin, size: buttonSize))
        self.addSubview(newButton)
        self.button = newButton
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer brigadir's question on how to bind to a mutable array.

zero'th - make titles an `NSMutableArray`

first - bind the array to your items

```
[cv bind:NSContentBinding 
    toObject:self 
    withKeyPath:@"titles" 
    options:NULL];
```

Second - when altering titles, make sure to modify the proxy.

e.g.

```
NSMutableArray *kvcTitles = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"titles"];
[kvcTitles removeLastObject];
```