# Is there a way to set up a NSCollectionView programmatically in Swift?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I'm coming from the iOS development and I am wondering if there is a way to set up a `NSCollectionView` programmatically like a `UICollectionView` in iOS? And add the `NSCollectionViewItems` in code. Or is the only way to set up a `NSCollectionView` to use bindings?

Thank You!

Comment: To answer the last question, no, you do not need to use bindings.  There is no view or control for which you need to use bindings.

Comment: But how can I do it without bindings?

Comment: Convert [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660626/how-to-create-nscollectionview-programatically-from-scratch) to swift.

Comment: There are however situations in which you need to use bindings, namely when the class and/or value of an object is not yet known at design time. Bindings to representedObject, vital for NSCollectionViewItem instances, are a prime example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @stevesliva for pointing me to  [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660626/how-to-create-nscollectionview-programatically-from-scratch). I converted it to Swift.
This is what I got.

I am creating a `NSCollectionView` in the `ViewController`:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var titles = [String]()
    var collectionView: NSCollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.titles = ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Pear", "Pineapple", "Grape", "Melon"]
        collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: self.view.frame)
        collectionView!.itemPrototype = CollectionViewItem()
        collectionView!.content = self.titles
        collectionView!.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxXMargin | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMinYMargin | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxYMargin
    
        var index = 0
        for title in titles {
            var item = self.collectionView!.itemAtIndex(index) as! CollectionViewItem
            item.getView().button?.title = self.titles[index]
            index++
        }
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!) 
    }
}
```

The created CollectionViewItem in the ViewController just load a view, where I set up the item view itself.

```
import Cocoa

class CollectionViewItem: NSCollectionViewItem {

    var itemView: ItemView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.itemView = ItemView(frame: NSZeroRect)
        self.view = self.itemView!
    }

    func getView() -> ItemView {
        return self.itemView!
    }
}
```

The view itself:

```
import Cocoa

class ItemView: NSView {

    let buttonSize: NSSize = NSSize(width: 100, height: 20)
    let itemSize: NSSize = NSSize(width: 120, height: 40)
    let buttonOrigin: NSPoint = NSPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

    var button: NSButton?

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: NSRect(origin: frameRect.origin, size: itemSize))
        let newButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(origin: buttonOrigin, size: buttonSize))
        newButton.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle
        self.addSubview(newButton)
        self.button = newButton;
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setButtonTitle(title: String) {
        self.button!.title = title
    }
}
```

To set the button title, I am using kind of a hack. (the for-loop in the ViewController) If there is a better way to set the title please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: To set the button title: In the for loop of the ViewController use: 'item.representedObject = title'. Then, in ItemView: 'NSButton *aButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 20)];
    [aButton bind:NSTitleBinding
         toObject:self
      withKeyPath:@"representedObject"
          options:@{NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption: @"No title"}];
    [self.view addSubview:aButton];' Don't use 'button.title = representedObject' since the representedObject won't be known at that time. The binding will resolve at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 2.0, you will need to change the `collectionView!.autoresizingMask` line to:

long hand:

```
collectionView?.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions([NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable,NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxXMargin,NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMinYMargin,NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable,NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewMaxYMargin])
```

or short hand:

```
collectionView?.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions([.ViewWidthSizable,.ViewMaxXMargin,.ViewMinYMargin,.ViewHeightSizable,.ViewMaxYMargin])
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to embed `NSCollectionView` within `NSScrollView`. Code below is in Swift 4

Setup `NSCollectionView`

```
let layout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4

collectionView = NSCollectionView()
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
collectionView.backgroundColors = [.clear]
collectionView.isSelectable = true
collectionView.register(
  Cell.self,
  forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell")
)
```

Setup `NSScrollView`

```
scrollView = NSScrollView()
scrollView.documentView = collectionView
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Here's a simple `NSCollectionViewItem`

```
class Cell: NSCollectionViewItem {
  let label = NSTextField()
  let imageView = NSImageView()

  override func loadView() {
    self.view = NSView()
    self.view.wantsLayer = true
  }
}
```