# Xamarin Mac - How to create and use an NSCollectionView with 100% code (no xib)?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, nscollectionview

Using the info from these SO answers:

- [How to create NSCollectionView programmatically from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660626/how-to-create-nscollectionview-programmatically-from-scratch)
- [Is there a way to set up a NSCollectionView programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061679/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-a-nscollectionview-programmatically-in-swift)

I've come up with the following:

```
using System;

using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public static CGPoint Origin = new CGPoint(10, 10);
        public static CGSize ButtonSize = new CGSize(80, 20);
        public static CGSize ItemSize = new CGSize(100, 40);

        public NSCollectionView CollectionView;
        public NSString[] Labels = { new NSString("Volvo"), new NSString("BMW"), new NSString("Ford"), new NSString("Mazda") };

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            CollectionView = new NSCollectionView(this.View.Frame);
            CollectionView.ItemPrototype = new ItemTemplate();
            CollectionView.Content = Labels;
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class ItemTemplate : NSCollectionViewItem
    {
        public ItemTemplate()
        {
        }

        public override void LoadView()
        {
            base.LoadView();

            this.View = new ItemView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;

                if (this.View != null)
                {
                    ((ItemView)this.View).Button.Title = value as NSString;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class ItemView: NSView
    {
        public NSButton Button;

        public ItemView(CGRect frameRect) : base(new CGRect(ViewController.Origin, ViewController.ItemSize))
        {
            Button = new NSButton(new CGRect(ViewController.Origin, ViewController.ButtonSize));
            this.AddSubview(Button);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting an error in this part of the code:

```
        public override void LoadView()
        {
            base.LoadView(); //<< ERROR happens here...

            this.View = new ItemView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
```

It looks like the code looks for a xib file to load (but I'm unsure whether the Xamarin framework may be calling the wrong API or whether NSCollectionViewItem cannot be used without a xib or something else is wrong with the code here altogether...)

Foundation.ObjCException
NSInternalInconsistencyException: -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: Sandbox_ItemTemplate in bundle (null).

[error/stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdCd7.png)

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)
  at AppKit.NSViewController.LoadView () [0x00027] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/7.2.0.3/src/Xamarin.Mac/AppKit/NSViewController.g.cs:872 
  at Sandbox.ItemTemplate.LoadView () [0x00001] in /Users/.../Projects/Xamarin_Mac___MacCollectionNew/Sandbox/ItemTemplate.cs:16 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at AppKit.NSCollectionView.set_Content (Foundation.NSObject[] value) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/7.2.0.3/src/Xamarin.Mac/AppKit/NSCollectionView.g.cs:1370 
  at Sandbox.ViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x0002f] in /Users/.../Projects/Xamarin_Mac___MacCollectionNew/Sandbox/ViewController.cs:29 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain(int,string[])
  at AppKit.NSApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00040] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/7.2.0.3/src/Xamarin.Mac/AppKit/NSApplication.cs:109 
  at Sandbox.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00007] in /Users/.../Projects/Xamarin_Mac___MacCollectionNew/Sandbox/Main.cs:10
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, when you init the `CollectionView`, you need to `View.AddSubview(CollectionView)`. Then `CollectionView` will show in the view.

Comment: I have hit the same problem today, have you found a solution @netboss?